# Leaflet polygon not working when added again

Tags: polygon, leaflet, geojson

I am using PruneCluster with Leaflet and I have custom logic happening to attempt to add and remove polygons when clusters are created. It mostly works, but I have an issue when I leave the page, and come back. I need all the markers that were put on the map previously, to be added again. This seems to work fine for markers without a geoJson layer, but when I try to add back a geoJson layer I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'min' of undefined` which is being triggered by this in Leaflet:

```
_getBitCode: function (/*Point*/ p, bounds) {
    var code = 0;

    if (p.x < bounds.min.x) { // left
        code |= 1;
    } else if (p.x > bounds.max.x) { // right
        code |= 2;
    }
    if (p.y < bounds.min.y) { // bottom
        code |= 4;
    } else if (p.y > bounds.max.y) { // top
        code |= 8;
    }

    return code;
},
```

My custom code to add shapes, when the marker is not clustered looks like this:

```
pruneCluster.PrepareLeafletMarker = function (leafletMarker, data) {
  if (data.isShape) {
    map.addLayer(data.geoJsonLayer);
  }
  leafletMarker.on('click', function (e) {
    GenerateRrosePopup(e, data.popupContent);
    if(data.isShape) {
      map.fitBounds(data.boundsForFit);
    }
  });
  leafletMarker.setIcon(data.icon);
};
```

`map.addLayer(data.geoJsonLayer)` is what causes the issue. I'm not sure why though because my geoJson object looks as I expect it to.

Why would this same code work for initially adding the geoJson layer, but then fail when I come back to the page and try to add the points and shapes I previously added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in Leaflet 0.8-dev

Comment: I am using leaflet version 1.7 but I have same problem